# Mixing Ext JS and Wicket

Tags: extjs, wicket

I have a problem related to Wicket and Ext JS. I have a text field in Ext JS and I want to add a Wicket ID to it. In Ext JS, text fields have limited properties. How can I do this?

Comment: The combination of extjs and wicket makes little sense at all. Two completely different approaches to the same problem. It's like an attempt to create an ncurses application with the QT toolkit.

Comment: @ammoQ ext js is 100% client side. wicket is 80% server side. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Karussell: An idiomatic ExtJS app uses Ajax all over the place. It consists of 99.8% JavaScript. I don't see how this mixes well with wicket, which depends on HTML markup and normal Get/Post requests.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two projects trying to integrate ext js into wicket:

http://code.google.com/p/wicket-extjs-integration/ gpl :(

http://code.google.com/p/wicket-ext/ apache license :)

Comment: The wicket-ext project is inactive (last modification was June 2009).

The wicket-extjs-integration is not very active either (last modification was Jan 2011). It also strangely uses AspectJ for a single aspect. Also, it's unclear how to use it since there are no docs. It mostly seems like it's translating the ExtJS api into Java form, but I'm not really sure of the benefit there. At some point you're going to have to code JS, so why not do this there?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the DOM to add custom attributes to the markup. See `Ext.Element`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a wicket:id then I presume that you are wanting to add a wicket component with that wicket:id to your page / component.  For this to work that wicket:id will need to be present in the html for your page / component at render time.  Therefore adding it to the DOM with javascript wont help you as wicket will never see it.

There are a few ext-js wicket integrations which may help you, but I haven't used them.  Try searching on the wicket mail list: http://old.nabble.com/Apache-Wicket-f13974.html

Answer (score 0):

The wicket-extjs-integration project is now available under the Apache license.  Licensing is a tricky subject, however, due to the fact that ExtJS code itself is GPL.  For details, see http://code.google.com/p/wicket-extjs-integration/wiki/Licensing.

The way we (Hippo) use it mostly is by letting the wicket component

1. set up the configuration and
2. implement component-bound services for the Ext component;
   e.g. a read/write JsonStore can be implemented in pure java.

It's also easy to subscribe to Ext events with a (java) event listener.

Typically, the Wicket component only needs to bootstrap the Ext component.  However, we've also had a few cases where we then needed to wrap a Wicket component in an Ext component.  This is also quite easily accomplished.  (see our Channel Manager code @ http://svn.onehippo.org/repos/hippo/hippo-cms7/addons/addon-channel-manager/trunk/)

Being able to compose the Ext component hierarchy has allowed us to extend our Wicket-based plugin mechanism to the Ext side.  E.g. Wicket plugins each instantiate a card/panel Ext component & those are aggregated on the wicket side in a component that instantiates an Ext tab panel.

The method annotation you mention is something we haven't needed; we typically trigger client-side code by emitting javascript code.  Probably a cleaner solution would be to fire an event.

The versions of Wicket and ExtJS used are a bit antiquated (1.4.xx & 3.4.x), something we'll be addressing on a short term.